# Best module for facebook Opengraph

Tags: social-network

I want to create an alumni association website. I want users to be able to sign up/login via facebook/linked in. Their details should be fetch from their social network profile. Are there any modules suitable for this criteria.

Comment: This could be due to my limited understanding of FB integration, but is the question actually related to opengraph? I was inclined to change the wording of the title, but since I'm uncertain, I didn't.

Comment: The module needed will bridge facebook with drupal. The data stored at facebook can be fetched into drupal through opengraph.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite option for facebook is the [Fboauth](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth). There are other solutions as well like [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) and [Facebook Connect](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect).

[Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) is intended for building Facebook apps. The Facebook connect functionality is just one of the features. While I was using the 6.x version I encountered many bugs, most were related to the constant api changes from facebook engineers. Have not used [Facebook Connect](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect). [Fboauth](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth) however looks simple and easily extendable. It was a simple task to import data from the fb profile into the drupal site.

This is a nice post about the subject:
http://grasmash.com/article/connecting-facebook-drupal-easy-way